# A variable declared as class member is accessible from one function but not from another

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a bit confused over here. As far as I understand this should work but it isn't!!.

```
class MyClass extends CI_Controller {
        private $myArray = array();
        public function function1(){
                array_push($this->myArray,'data');
                echo sizeof($this->myArray);      
        }
        public function function2(){
                echo sizeof($this->myArray);
        }
}
```

So first I call localhost/MyClass/function1 which will render a view and add some data to the array (text data nothing special) with a button that will call function2. The first function will output the size of array lets say 2 but calling function2 -in the right order by clicking the button- will output size of 0. Any idea how to achieve this?

I tried the following:

```
1- private $myArray = [];
2- private $myArray; // then i initiated it in the __construct() function
3- made it public
```

## EDIT

The problem is after filling the array with data from the first function and calling the second function i am getting a size of 0 not the actual size after filling it.

Comment: sizeof, not sizeif

Comment: @OscarZarrus fixed, its was a typo

Comment: How to achieve what? You've described exactly how the code works and nothing else.

Comment: So, the problem persists?

Comment: @OscarZarrus i added what i want, sorry

Comment: As these are separate http requests, and PHP doesn't maintain state between requests, this is to be expected..... you need to persist the data somehow (database, filesystem, cache, session) and reload on the second request

Comment: @MarkBaker does it mean that the whole object is reinitialized on each call ?

Comment: @YamenNassif - Yes, that's how PHP works.... every individual http request is stateless, PHP doesn't maintain state between requests unless you code it to do so using session, database, cache, file, shared memory, etc... each individual request is processed in isolation, with nothing to connect it to any previous request unless you have coded it to do so

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks, I think you need to add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php //php 7.0.8

    class MyClass {
        private $myArray = array();
        public function function1(){
                array_push($this->myArray,'data');
                echo sizeof($this->myArray);      
        }
        public function function2(){
                echo sizeof($this->myArray);
        }
}
    $x = new MyClass;
    $x->function1(); // populate array with 1 element and echo (1)
    $x->function2(); // echo the pre-populated array (1)

 $x = new MyClass;
    $x->function2(); // echo the no-populated array (0)
    $x->function1(); // populate array with 1 element and echo (1)
?>
```

You must call function1() first or you can call on construct for automatically load on class call

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/DMDS43882)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on the code which call the `MyClass`,
One may be is not in a php session,  and you can try to make `myArray` to be `static`.
so the `myArray` will not be what you think.
Can you put the more code to see?
Are you call the php file by `ajax`?

Comment: localhost/MyClass/function1 this will call the functions.... its CI again